# LibGDX - How does Gdx.graphics.getWidth() return the width of the display surface?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to understand more about inside world of LibGDX.

For example inside `Graphics.java`, I find the following:

```
/** @return the width in pixels of the display surface */ 
public int getWidth ();
```

However, I can't find the source code of `getWidth()` method.

Where can I find the `getWidth()` method source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a different implementation of that interface for each of the available backends/platforms.

- [AndroidGraphics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGraphics.java): For the Android backend.
- [LwjglGraphics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglGraphics.java): For the desktop backend.
- [GwtGraphics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtGraphics.java): For the browser backend
- [IOSGraphics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-robovm/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/iosrobovm/IOSGraphics.java): for the iOS backend.
- [MockGraphics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/headless/mock/graphics/MockGraphics.java): for the server backend.
- [JglfwGraphics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-jglfw/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/jglfw/JglfwGraphics.java): for the alternative desktop backend.

In the LWJGL backend, the implementation looks like this for example:

```
public int getWidth () {
    if (canvas != null)
        return Math.max(1, canvas.getWidth());
    else
        return (int)(Display.getWidth() * Display.getPixelScaleFactor());
}
```

The actual implementation is delegated once more to either the AWT Canvas, or the LWJGL Display.

The general idea behind these kind of interfaces can be found everywhere in LibGDX. You can also do platform specific code yourself. It is descibed in [the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

Answer (score 4):

From the libgdx docs (Graphics.java) :

> This interface encapsulates communication with the graphics processor.
>   Depending on the available hardware and the current Application
>   configuration, access to `GL20` and `GL30` are provided here.

Basically, `Graphics.java` represents an interface. The `getWidth` method is an abstract method in the interface which needs to be overriden in all classes that implement the interface.

If you wish to see the code inside the `getWidth` method, you need to look at one of the classes that implement the Graphics interface.